# Learning about lexical scanning and parsing from the ground up

Tags: parsing, tokenize, lexical-analysis

I was wondering if somebody could suggest projects that implement simple lexers and parsers (without the help of tools like lex and yacc) for me to look at the source.  I'm interested in the subject, and before I would like to see and study how they can be implemented manually.

Comment: Hand-written lexers are just very ugly and verbose implementations of the regular expressions that form the lexmes, with some boilerplate code for (among other things) storing the matched strings, perhaps converting integer literals from strings.Chances are you'll never have to write one yourself, so apart from the gritty implementation details of the actual matching, there's nothing to be learnt from them compared to a tokenizer using lex.

Comment: @delnan - That is absolutely incorrect. I've seen very elegant parsers written using parser combinators that allow ultimate control of how the result is produced.

Comment: @Chaos: I know *very* well that parsers can (and often are, if the authors are sane) be written elegantly. I was talking about **tokenizers**, which are an entirely different matter.

Comment: @delnan - My apologies, I miss-read your comment.

Comment: @delnan, you can use parsing combinators to build tokenisers as well.

Comment: @Sk-logic: I suppose it's possible, but is anyone actually doing that (a quick search indicates no, but that may be my google-fu)? It always seemed to me that at least 99% of all tokenizers in existence are FSAs.

Comment: @delnan, it is the most common approach with Parsec and alike. Actually, handwritten parsers are often lexerless - there is no dedicated tokenisation stage, token recognisers are naturally embedded into the parser itself. Some generated parsers (most notably PEG-based) are doing the same thing. It allows much more flexible syntax, and performance penalty is not significant.

Comment: @SK-logic: Of course having a seperate tokenizer is optional, but IMHO this doesn't make parsers who get along without them tokenizers. If someone used e.g. parsec to generate a list of tokens, and then another parser to make sense of those, fair enough, but a parser that works directly on strings (instead of lists of tokens) is just a parser to me.

Comment: I generally hand code lexers.  I find that a FSA diagram is the easiest way to understand a token set.  Well-organized code is next.  A set of regular expressions is the hardest.  It can be very hard to see if you've created ambiguities when you code them directly as regular expressions.  Generating good error messages is typically only possible with a hand-rolled tokenizer.  Only the very best automated tokenizer-generators produce code that's faster than a hand-coded tokenizer, and that generated code is usually much uglier.

Comment: @delnan, could you please elaborate a bit more? My point is that you don't need a list of tokens at all - especially if tokensation process depends on context. See the Katahdin language for an example of such a syntax.

Comment: @SK-logic: Of course one doesn't need tokens at all - but if there are no tokens, there's no tokenizer either, so a parser that doesn't consume tokens is a parser without a tokenizers.

Comment: @delnan: the only reason why (probably) nobody uses parser for a separate lexical analysis step is simply because it doesn't bring any advantages, not because it's difficult or anything. It's actually trivial.

Answer (score 1):

The Dragon book is very good on this.  Its a very in depth look at the entire compiler technology.  This includes a large section on parsing and parse trees.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools

Answer (score 0):

Go to antlr.org and read about how ANTLR works. Also *The Definitive ANTLR Reference* is definitely worth the money. Plus ANTLR has a large and very helpful user community.  Yes ANTLR is a tool but you can look at the source. Developing your own lexers and parsers is probably not something you want to do in the long run but you will, of course, write your own grammars.  The ANTLR v3 grammar is very nice to use.

Comment: He's trying to learn how parsers and tokenizers work. You point him to the source code of a parser and tokenizer *generator*. That's like explaining the machines at a car factory's assembly line when asked about the inner workings of a car.

Comment: Hello?  This is an insulting and uninformed criticism. I know he's trying to learn how they work.  Different lexers, parsers, and tree parsers work different ways.  The ANTLR documentation explains all this very clearly and is much more readable that most of the older stuff on the topic.

Comment: OP is asking for an example of a simple lexer and parser built without such tools. If you want to argue that he should start with such tools to get the general approach without getting caught up in implementation details (btw, I can't judge it but I'd be surprised if ANTLR material was entirely uninfluenced by the fact ANTLR generates LL parsers), alright (not my downvote), but at least you should clearly state that. Also consider that most widespread/popular parsers *are* handwritten.

Comment: If you write a simple ANTLR grammar and use the ANTLR tool to generate a lexer you will get a readable example of a simple lexer in your choice of programming languages, including Java and C++.  Remember that a lexer has to be customized to a grammar -- there is no such thing as a general tokenizer.  One could also do the same exercise using other tools to see how different lexers would handle tokenizing that same grammar. This exercise should lead toward a variety of useful information.  OP could also try hand writing a tokenizer for his chosen grammar.

Comment: @PeggySu, FYI: ANTLR does not generate C++ source (the generated C code may by C++ compliant (or whatever it's called), but it's C, not C++).

Comment: Sorry, I meant C#. I always use the Java option myself so didn't notice my typo.

Comment: Yeah, C code from ANTLR has little resemblance to the grammar that was fed to it. It's also not very readable, nobody would write such code by hand. So there is some teaching value in doing this experiment, but not much.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see a code for handwritten parsers then I suggest looking for gcc and various xml parsers. You can start reading from [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GNU_C_Compiler_Internals/GNU_C_Compiler_Architecture_3_4) about gcc architecture. Type *"xml parser source code"* in your favorite search engine and you will have plenty of examples of xml parsers. If you are more interested in learning how to write *native* parser libraries, which don't require extra step of code generation, you can look at boost::Spirit (C++) or AXE (C++0x). Also check [this table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_parser_generators) for various projects, some of them offer source code, but you will need to do mining yourself.